# Data structure MongoDB for Insurance policies

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to have some feedback about the best way to organize data for an insurance company (and in general).
I am using MongoDB and i'm unsure about a thing.
lets say i have different prices for different coverages on the same policy, on top of that various cases based on the annual income of the company who will sign the policy.

- #1. Coverage -> 5.000.000 - Annual income -> 1.000.000 - price -> 500
- #2. Coverage -> 5.000.000 - Annual income -> 1.500.000 - price -> 550

Then i can add extensions to that policy (in this case just 4 types)

- #1.Basic extension -> 120 - Advanced extension -> 150
- #1.Basic extension -> 150 - Advanced extension -> 170

I was thing about saving every policy in a collection, everyone with their characteristics.
So, lets take this one as an example.

Collection: policies

Entry:

- id
- name: name of the policy as it is written in the docs
- prices: [{id: 0, price: 500, income_range: [0, 1.000.000], coverage_range: [0,5.000.000], extensions: [120, 150]}, {{id: 1, price: 550, income_range: [1.000.001, 1.500.000], coverage_range: [0,5.000.000], extensions: [150, 170]}
- other_general_stuff

OR

Collection: policies

Entry:

- id
- name: name of the policy as it is written in the docs
- prices: [{id: 0, price: 500, income_range: 0, coverage_range: 0, extensions: l1}, {{id: 1, price: 550, income_range: 1, coverage_range: 0, extensions: l2}
- income_ranges: [{id: 0, range: [0, 1.000.000]}, {id: 1, range: [1.000.001, 1.500.000]}]
- cover_ranges: [{id: 0, range: [0, 5.000.000]}, {id: 1, range: [5.000.000, 7.000.000]}]
- extensions: {l1: {basic: 120, adv: 150}, l2: {basic: 150, adv: 170}}

I mean considering there are different products this i just a tiny example, but what concerns me is for ex. the ranges property, is it ok in this type of db to scructure it like the second example, is there a way of accessing those property in an easy way, or is it better to write the entire thing directly into the 'prices field'.

I have not much experience, so I am trying to figure out what is the best practice to follow.
I know that there are many possible solutions, but is this entirely wrong? Can someone give me a feedback or point me to some nice resources.

Thank you

Comment: See [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) for some related information.

Comment: Hey i've already read that, maybe someone here could give me a direct feedback, an example or a similar case. Thank you